# How to Scroll UITextField when hides by Keyboard on Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I'm with the classic problem, that keyboard of iOS hides the UITextField at bottom screen. So, the solution at web only solves for <= Swift3.
So, How I solve this in Swift4?

Full Screen:

[image]

Keyboard hides my UITextField:

[image]

I've tried this article: https://medium.com/@dzungnguyen.hcm/autolayout-for-scrollview-keyboard-handling-in-ios-5a47d73fd023
But the `self.constraintContentHeight.constant` "is not member" of ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow that medium post here is your solution:

self.constraintContentHeight.constant which you are not getting is actually the IBOutlet for the height constraint of your content view.

so you need to set the connection to that.
Thats it. enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the framework to easily handle That is [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Comment: I would not like to use third librarys, is there anyone in the world who does not use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I personally use. It is an NSLayoutContraint. In the storyboard, you can select the Bottom Layout Guide and change it's class to KeyboardNSLayoutConstraint.

```
import UIKit

public class KeyboardNSLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    private var offset : CGFloat = 0
    private var keyboardVisibleHeight : CGFloat = 0

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        offset = constant

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardLayoutConstraint.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardLayoutConstraint.keyboardWillHideNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let frameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
                let frame = frameValue.cgRectValue
                keyboardVisibleHeight = frame.size.height
                 //If device is an iPhone X, it changes the layout constraint to accomodate for the bottom bar
                if (UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone10,3") || (UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone10,6") {
                    keyboardVisibleHeight = keyboardVisibleHeight - 34
                }
            }

            self.updateConstant()
            switch (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber, userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber) {
            case let (.some(duration), .some(curve)):

                let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve.uintValue)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration.doubleValue), delay: 0, options: options, animations: {                            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layoutIfNeeded()
                        return
                }, completion: { finished in })
            default:

                break
            }

        }

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHideNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        keyboardVisibleHeight = 0
        self.updateConstant()

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

            switch (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber, userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber) {
            case let (.some(duration), .some(curve)):

                let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve.uintValue)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration.doubleValue), delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layoutIfNeeded()
                    return
                }, completion: { finished in })
            default: break
            }
        }
    }

    func updateConstant() {
        self.constant = offset + keyboardVisibleHeight
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update `[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]` to `[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]` it will give you the height of keyboard + the keyboard bar(if enabled).

[Your Medium post refrence](https://medium.com/@dzungnguyen.hcm/autolayout-for-scrollview-keyboard-handling-in-ios-5a47d73fd023)

Answer (score 0):

**Take outlet of the topConstraint that is superview of textfield than write some code in the delegate method like this**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

if textfield==txt1{

containerView(superview of textfield).topConstraint.constraint = -100 (According to you choice)

} else if textfield == txt2{

containerView(superview of textfield).topConstraint.constraint = -120 (According to you choice)


}

}



func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

containerView(superview of textfield).topConstraint.constraint = 0 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add observer event of keyboard will change that is the better than.

```
extension UIView {


    func bindToKeyboard() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let curveFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let targetFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = targetFrame.origin.y - curveFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

After that just call it in viewDidLoad() but make sure you must set delegate to it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Textfield delegation
    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self

    view.bindToKeyboard()

}
```